# Recognising touch events in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitouch

If the user writes "t" on the particular touch area, the iPhone should recognise it and it should be displayed.

Where should the user write? Is there any specific area like UItextfield and how is it recoginised (letter written by the user)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is something that's called UITextField and you can access it's properties. But you should (TOTALLY) read through the developer.apple.com stuff first. There are also some nice videos on youtube and on apple that will help you get an entry.

**Please!** don't be lazy and learn about the basics! If you have any further questions about usage or something else: Use the Forum Search! Google it! Then ask your question!

Comment: who's just so funny to downvote an acceptable answer without commentating what should be improved?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can subclass the UIVIew  and create an new custom View.
2. Define the following methods:

touchesBegan:withEvent:
touchesMoved:withEvent:
touchesEnded:withEvent: 
touchesCancelled:withEvent:

Each time user starts touching and ends the touch record the set of of points user  has traveled and use these stored values in drawRect Method to draw lines between them.

1. Implement  drawRect:  method in your custom view and do the drawing of lines according to the users touch points.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider creating a gesture recognizer for this. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) is the basic guide that can get you started.